# Guard against filtering an empty JS object

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
for (var key in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    if (obj[key].id === foo.id) {
      // do something
    }
  }
}
```

I'm checking whether the object is not empty before doing any functionality, because the array is populated later on user interaction.

For better readability, I want to do something like this:

```
const result = obj.filter((item) => item.id === foo.id)
return result[0]
```

This, however, will produce an error: `obj.filter is not a function` since the object is empty when the page renders and is populated later.
Question is - how do I simplify this and at the same time guard against filtering the empty object in the most simple way?

---

EDIT: Adding sample data structure for `obj`

```
{
    0: { id: 2, name: 'John', category: 'Repair' },
    1: { id: 3, name: 'William', category: 'Maintenance' }
}
```

Comment: `(obj || []).filter ...`

Comment: Where is `foo` coming from?

Comment: do you really use a `for ... in` loop for arrays?

Comment: @ShammelLee it's irrelevant in this case, the question is around the previous check.

Comment: @NinaScholz By asking this question, I'm trying not to.

Comment: are we speaking about an array or an array like object?

Comment: perhaps `activityMetrics` isn't an array (but is otherwise truthy) then @abpetkov - not sure how that even relates to the code you posted though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an empty array as default value.

```
const result = (obj || []).filter(item => item.id === foo.id);
```

or use an explicit check with [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray).

```
const result = Array.isArray(obj) && obj.filter(item => item.id === foo.id);
```

The result is either an array or `false`.

If you like to get an empty array, you could use an array as default value as well, like

```
const result = Array.isArray(obj) && obj.filter(item => item.id === foo.id) || [];
```

Now, after giving the structure of the object, you could use

```js
var getItem = (obj, id) => obj && typeof obj === 'object' && Object
        .keys(obj)
        .filter(key => obj[key].id === id)
        .map(key => obj[key]),
    obj = {
        0: { id: 2, name: 'John', category: 'Repair' },
        1: { id: 3, name: 'William', category: 'Maintenance' }
    },
    result1 = getItem(obj, 3),
    result2 = getItem(null, 3);

console.log(result1);
console.log(result2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I didn't mention I'm using React, but that shouldn't matter. The first example still produces the `is not a function` error. The second one is good, but it's checking for an Array instead of an Object and that will always return false.

Comment: please add the data structure of `obj`.

Comment: `{ "id": 42, "name": "John", "category": "Repair" }`

Comment: is that `obj` or just an item of the array ...?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Meant to paste this: `{"0":{"id":2,"name":"John","category":"Repair"},"1":{"id":3,"name":"William","category":"Maintenance"}`

Comment: Last snipper does it. Thanks @NinaScholz!

Answer (score 0):

Make it a function that takes the object as argument. Then just make sure you call the function with a valid, initialised argument. And then you might as well also pass `foo` as argument:

```
const f = (obj, foo) => obj.filter((item) => item.id === foo.id)
// ... 
return f(obj, foo)[0]
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var obj = {
  "0": { id: 2, name: 'John', category: 'Repair' },
  "1": { id: 3, name: 'William', category: 'Maintenance' }
};

var keys = Object.keys(obj);

for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  var k = keys[i];
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
    console.log(obj[k].name + ' works in ' + obj[k].category);
  }
}
```